# DHTML - Index of clicked button

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I have just started coding my asset management page where admin can manage all assets from the web page. From this page, admin can rename the assets and add the assets (which are not yet added in the db) to the db using the form interface.

Below is the embeded html code in the php file

```
<tr>

    <td><img src="<?php echo $newAssetsUrl.$asset->name ?>" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
    <td><span name="inboxImgName"><?php echo $asset->name?></span>
        <input type="button" name="inboxEdit" value="Rename" onclick="alert(this.name),toggleInboxEditSave(<?php echo $i?>)"/>
        <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden"
            name="inboxNewImageName" value="<?php $asset->name ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $asset->getTypeName()?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Add"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="imageName[]" value="<?php echo $asset->name ?>"/>

</tr>
```

Now the javascript which toggles the show/hide the edit box to rename the asset name and toggles the button's text to save/edit

```
function toggleInboxEditSave(idx){

    btn = document.getElementsByName("inboxEdit")[idx];

    curState = btn.value;

    lbl = document.getElementsByName("inboxImgName")[idx];
    txt = document.getElementsByName("inboxNewImageName")[idx];

    if (curState == "Rename"){

        btn.value = "Save";
        //alert("going to save");
        lbl.style.visibility = "hidden";
        txt.style.visibility = "visible";

    }else{

        btn.value = "Rename";

        lbl.style.visibility = "visible";
        txt.style.visibility = "hidden";

    }

}
```

I am going to implement the code in "Add"'s click event which will add the entry in the db and remove it from the html page.

This is working fine so for me. How ever, I just want to avoid the **seeding** of the index number using this code

```
 toggleInboxEditSave(<?php echo $i?>)
```

The reason being, I am planning to implement the ajax, and I will remove the rows dynamically after assets are added. which makes my javascript fail because the index numbers wont be valid anymore, except the user clicks on "add" button (which I am going to add).

**Can you suggest any better way to get the index of the button being clicked?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<tr>

    <td><img src="<?php echo $newAssetsUrl.$asset->name ?>" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
    <td><span name="inboxImgName_<?php echo $asset->name?>"><?php echo $asset->name?></span>
        <input type="button" name="inboxEdit_<?php echo $asset->name?>" value="Rename" onclick="alert(this.name),toggleInboxEditSave(this)"/>
        <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden"
            name="inboxNewImageName_<?php echo $asset->name?>" value="<?php $asset->name ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $asset->getTypeName()?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="Add"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="imageName[]" value="<?php echo $asset->name ?>"/>

</tr>
```

function toggleInboxEditSave(obj){

```
btn = obj;

curState = btn.value;
curid = (btn.name).split("_")[1];

lbl = document.getElementsByName("inboxImgName"+curid)[0];
txt = document.getElementsByName("inboxNewImageName"+curid)[0];

if (curState == "Rename"){

    btn.value = "Save";
    //alert("going to save");
    lbl.style.visibility = "hidden";
    txt.style.visibility = "visible";

}else{

    btn.value = "Rename";

    lbl.style.visibility = "visible";
    txt.style.visibility = "hidden";

}
```

}

Hope this helps you

Comment: this works, well, i forgot to mention, i was looking if there is any alternate way other than **suffixing the index**

Comment: Here index is not used right? I haven't used the index in my code. I have used only this keyword

Comment: Yes, your code uses the "name" not the "index" but its similar which makes the form submition makes lot of form elements to return instead of the array of elements with one name. I hope you understood what I am looking for. but I accepted above answer.  Looking forward to have a workaround to have only the array of elements (form elements with same name)

Comment: I just got an Idea something like I will place all controls inside <div> and all form elements inside it <form><div1><text[]/><btn1/><checkbox[]></div><div2><text[]/><btn2/><checkbox[]></div></form>. so when the form is submitted i get arrary of elements and yet I can handle the controls at the client easily by accesing div's child elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<input type="button" ... onclick="alert(this.name),toggleInboxEditSave(this)"/>
```

and later

```
function toggleInboxEditSave(node){
    btn = node;
```

inside of onclick handler, **this** points to the owner html node

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it like this. Key things to note here are

Name of form elements is array (t[], c[]). This makes the server side parsing easier
Each set of elements are within a parent with an id (here is it div)
In the JS, access all child elements using the getElementsByTagName

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Send'])){
    var_dump($_POST);
}else{
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 

    $i = 0;
    while ($i<5){
    ?>
        <div id="d_<?php echo $i?>">
            <input type="text" name="t[]<?php  $i?>">
            <input type="checkbox" name="c[]<?php  $i?>">
            <input type="button"
                name="b_<?php echo $i?>" value="Button<?php echo $i?>"
                onclick="clicked(this)"><br/>
        </div>
    <?php
        $i++; 
    }?>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Send"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function clicked(btn){
            idx = (btn.name).split("_")[1];
            div = document.getElementById("d_"+idx);
            c = div.getElementsByTagName("input");
            //alert(div.getElementById("t"));

            for (i=0;i<c.length;i++){

                alert(c[i].name);
            }
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        }

    </script>
<?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```